# InvalidCastException when trying to Sum datatable rows with LINQ

Tags: vb.net, linq, group-by

Hi i am trying to sum all my datatable values to one row. but i retrieve a InvalidCastException:

> Failed to convert an object of
>   typeWhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[System.Object,System.Data.DataRow],VB$AnonymousType_0`4[System.Object,System.Double,System.Decimal,System.Decimal]]
>   to type System.Data.DataTable.

**SQL Datatypes:**

1. NAME_AGE string
2. LON money
3. sal_tjformon money
4. sal_sjuklon money

   ```
     Private Function GroupByName(dataTable As DataTable) As DataTable

       Dim result = dataTable.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(
           Function(row) row.Item("NAME_AGE")).Select(Function(group) New With {
               .Grp = group.Key,
               .LON = group.Sum(Function(r) Decimal.Parse(r.Item("LON"))),
               .sal_tjformon = group.Sum(Function(r) Decimal.Parse(r.Item("sal_tjformon"))),
               .sal_sjuklon = group.Sum(Function(r) Decimal.Parse(r.Item("sal_sjuklon")))
           })

       Return result
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The LINQ statement returns an `IEnumerable(Of <anonymous_type>)`. There are two problems with this. First of all, your function returns a `DataTable`, which your object definitely is not. Secondly of all, you can't return an anonymous type from a function call.

If you want to return the select result, you have to create an explicit type (a class) and return the `IEnumerable(Of MyType)`, like in the code below. I strongly advice to set an explicit type to the `Grp` property (like `String`?).

```
Class GroupNameAgeResult
    Public Property Grp As Object
    Public Property LON As Decimal
    Public Property sal_tjformon As Decimal
    Public Property sal_sjuklon As Decimal
End Class

Private Function GroupByName(dataTable As DataTable) As IEnumerable(Of GroupNameAgeResult)
    Dim result = dataTable.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(Function(row) row.Item("NAME_AGE")) _
                 .Select(Function(grp) New GroupNameAgeResult() With
                                       {.Grp = grp.Key,
                                        .LON = grp.Sum(Function(r) Decimal.Parse(r.Item("LON").ToString)),
                                        .sal_tjformon = grp.Sum(Function(r) Decimal.Parse(r.Item("sal_tjformon").ToString)),
                                        .sal_sjuklon = grp.Sum(Function(r) Decimal.Parse(r.Item("sal_sjuklon").ToString))})

    Return result
End Function
```

If you want to return a `DataTable`, you can define this, loop over the groups and add a row. You can return afterwards the result. See example code below.

```
Private Function GroupByName(dataTable As DataTable) As DataTable
    Dim result As New DataTable()
    result.Columns.Add("Grp", GetType(Object))
    result.Columns.Add("LON", GetType(Decimal))
    result.Columns.Add("sal_tjformon", GetType(Decimal))
    result.Columns.Add("sal_sjuklon", GetType(Decimal))

    For Each grp In dataTable.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(Function(row) row.Item("NAME_AGE"))
        Dim row As DataRow = result.NewRow()
        row.Item("Grp") = grp.Key
        row.Item("LON") = grp.Sum(Function(r) Decimal.Parse(r.Item("LON").ToString))
        row.Item("sal_tjformon") = grp.Sum(Function(r) Decimal.Parse(r.Item("sal_tjformon").ToString))
        row.Item("sal_sjuklon") = grp.Sum(Function(r) Decimal.Parse(r.Item("sal_sjuklon").ToString))
        result.Rows.Add(row)
    Next

    Return result
End Function
```

Last but not least. I strongly advice you to turn on "Option strict" (you can set this in the project properties -> Compile). You'll notice many more (possible) errors with your code (even the small function from this question).

Comment: Sorry but my vb isen't the best when i use the example to return a datatable i get and error that tells me that grp is not declared. Do i really need to declare it?